# Proguard warnings: can't find referenced class scala.*

Tags: java, android, scala, compiler-construction, proguard

After upgrading to new Android tools, I am getting following warnings from Proguard:

```
Warning: scala.xml.EntityRef: can't find referenced class scala.xml.EntityRef$$anonfun$text$1
Warning: scala.xml.dtd.AttrDecl$: can't find referenced class scala.xml.dtd.AttrDecl$$anonfun$toString$1
Warning: scala.collection.mutable.LinkedListLike: can't find referenced class scala.collection.mutable.LinkedListLike$$anonfun$insert$1
Warning: scala.xml.NamespaceBinding: can't find referenced class scala.xml.NamespaceBinding$$anonfun$toString$1
Warning: scala.xml.NamespaceBinding: can't find referenced class scala.xml.NamespaceBinding$$anonfun$buildString$1
Warning: scala.xml.MetaData$: can't find referenced class scala.xml.MetaData$$anonfun$toString$1
Warning: scala.xml.MetaData$: can't find referenced class scala.xml.MetaData$$anonfun$toString1$1
Warning: scala.collection.immutable.BitSet: can't find referenced class scala.collection.immutable.BitSet$$anonfun$$plus$1
Warning: scala.collection.immutable.BitSet: can't find referenced class scala.collection.immutable.BitSet$$anonfun$$minus$1
Warning: scala.collection.mutable.FlatHashTable$$anonfun$checkConsistent$1: can't find referenced class scala.collection.mutable.FlatHashTable$$anonfun$checkConsistent$1$$anonfun$apply$mcVI$sp$1
Warning: scala.collection.immutable.RedBlack: can't find referenced class scala.collection.immutable.RedBlack$Empty
Warning: scala.collection.immutable.BitSet$: can't find referenced class scala.collection.immutable.BitSet$$anonfun$$plus$1
Warning: scala.collection.immutable.BitSet$: can't find referenced class scala.collection.immutable.BitSet$$anonfun$$minus$1
Warning: scala.xml.EntityRef$: can't find referenced class scala.xml.EntityRef$$anonfun$text$1
Warning: scala.Either: can't find referenced class scala.Either$$anonfun$joinLeft$1
... (more) ...
```

Any hints why Proguard cannot find these classes? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you building? With Ant? Sbt? Maven? And where did you get your setup from in the first place?

Assuming that you're using Ant and the setup described at http://lamp.epfl.ch/~michelou/android/ then have you updated your build-scala.xml and proguard templates to the ones that were checked in recently to support the latest Android SDK?

Comment: +1 Thank you for hint, I have copied scala specific rules from their `proguard.cfg`. (I am using my own `build.xml` that is more similar to the SDK version.)

Answer (score 5):

If you look at the internals of the listed classes from scala-library.jar (version 2.9.1), you'll see that they reference classes that don't exist at all. It looks like a compiler problem to me. The references are not fundamental for processing and running the code though, so you can let ProGuard accept the jar with this option:

```
-dontwarn scala.**
```

Comment: From which version of Proguard this works? I am using the "Android's" version and it still shows the Scala warnings.

Comment: +1 It seems to help with `-dontwarn scala.**` (two asterisks).

Comment: This answer saved my life. +1.