# How to automatically generate proguard-android.txt?

Tags: android, adt, proguard

Reading all the wonderful things the new [ProGuard Improvements for Android](http://tools.android.com/recent/proguardimprovements) do, I switched to to the new scheme by *uncommenting* the following line in a newly created project:

```
proguard.config=${sdk.dir}\tools\proguard\proguard-android.txt;proguard-project.txt
```

But when I try to export this project's APK, I am greeted with the following message:

> Invalid proguard configuration file path
>   C:\android-sdk-windows\tools\proguard\proguard-android.txt does not
>   exist or is not a regular file

Well, I checked the directory `C:\android-sdk-windows\tools\proguard` and, sure enough, while this directory exists and has subdirectories and even a README file, `proguard-android.txt` is nowhere to be found.

BTW, I tried it with `:` instead of `;` but that didn't seem to change anything.

Isn't Eclipse+ADT+Proguard supposed to generate this file automatically for me? What am I missing?

Also, where can I find a "standard" [default set of rules for Android](http://tools.android.com/recent/proguardimprovements) proguard-android.txt so that I can copy it over to its missing slot?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It *should* either be generated or come with your sdk (I think). However, here is a link to the one that I have (tools r19). 
http://pastebin.com/7rNJkns0

Comment: Thanks +1 for the link. I will accept your answer if no one suggests an explanation for why it wasn't automatically generated by my latest SDK (tools r19).

Comment: What you have is not similar to what is automatically generated. What I see that is automatically generated is all informational comments, with no actual rules in it.

Answer (score 2):

New Projects or old ones converted when changing API now in project.properties link to

```
proguard.config=${sdk.dir}\tools\proguard\proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt
```

You can simply link your projects proguard config by commenting the line and adding

```
proguard.config=proguard-project.txt
```

to it.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Your declaration is:

```
proguard.config=${sdk.dir}\tools\proguard\proguard-android.txt;proguard-project.txt
```

The Correct declaration is (`:` instead of`;`):

```
proguard.config=${sdk.dir}\tools\proguard\proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt
```

Comment: To end the game of "Spot the Difference": There's a colon instead of a semi-colon after `proguard-android.txt`. But the OP says he already tried that and it didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend creating a new project and copying the proguard-project.txt from there.

In eclipse, you can do that by going to File --> New --> Other --> Android --> Android Application Project. It's just in the root directory of the new project.