# Proguard returned with error code 1 error when signing apk with many external libraries

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-proguard

I am using Eclipse for Mac.
When I want to export a signed apk I get a "Proguard returned with error code 1. See console" error.

- I have these 2 files in my project root folder:
  "proguard-android.txt" and "project.properties"
- Inside project.properties I have:

  target=android-17
  proguard.config=proguard-project.txt
  android.library.reference.1=../google-play-services_lib
  android.library.reference.2=../FacebookSDK

Among many other warnings I get when I try to create a signed apk, I get:

```
com.my.app.va.debug.ConfigureLog4j: can't find referenced class de.mindpipe.android.logging.log4j.LogConfigurator

com.my.app.va.debug.HockeyAppHelper: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.ExceptionHandler
```

I already put these lines inside "proguard-android.txt" , but the errors persist:

```
-keep public class de.mindpipe.android.logging.**
-dontwarn de.mindpipe.android.logging.**
-keep public class net.hockeyapp.**
-dontwarn net.hockeyapp.**
```

What could I be doing wrong?

**UPDATE:**
I have changed the filename from "proguard-android.txt" to "proguard-project" and added this to my Proguard, and the "referenced class" error messages are gone:

```
-dontwarn de.mindpipe.android.**
-keep public class de.mindpipe.android.**

-dontwarn net.hockeyapp.android.**
-keep public class net.hockeyapp.android.**
```

Neverthless... Is this an actual solution? or, am I just hiding the problem?

*Other warnings still persist:*

```
Warning: com.facebook.widget.UserSettingsFragment: can't find referenced method 'android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity getActivity()' in class com.facebook.widget.UserSettingsFragment
Warning: there were 138 unresolved references to program class members.
```

Answer (score 0):

The proguard file name should be defined in **project.properties** if using Eclipse or in build.gradle if using Gradle or Android Studio.

It usually contains **proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt**.

You should also include the following:

```
-keep class android.support.v4.app.** { *; } 
-keep interface android.support.v4.app.** { *; }
```

More official info at http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html.

Some other relevant stackoverflow discussions: [How to config my proguard-project.txt file to remove just Logs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14123866/how-to-config-my-proguard-project-txt-file-to-remove-just-logs) and [How to automatically generate proguard-android.txt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11020256/how-to-automatically-generate-proguard-android-txt)