# Force Close with AdMob; developing for android 2.2

Tags: android, admob

I have been trying for the past two days now to implement Admob ads into an app which is being developed for Android 2.2 and above. I have searched online and tried all of the answers I have found, but still, nothing. I followed all the instructions on the admob site, and have tried both the java (posted below) and the xml version. Everytime I use xml, I get the error "failed to instantiate com.google.ads.AdView". I have tried the fixes for that but it still crashes. So far I have changed the "minSdkVersion" to 8 (for developing on 2.2), and the "target" to android=14, which is needed for the AdMob sdk. Any help would be much appreciated!

**Menu class**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import com.google.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.ads.AdSize;
import com.google.ads.AdView;

public class Menu extends Activity{

Button start, HTP;
private AdView adView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bStart);
    HTP = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bHTP);


    start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(Menu.this,
                    MyGameActivity.class);
            Menu.this.startActivity(myIntent);
            }
        });

    HTP.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(Menu.this,
                    HowToPlay.class);
            Menu.this.startActivity(myIntent);
        }
    });


    // Create the adView
    adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "publisher id in quotes");

    // Lookup your LinearLayout assuming it’s been given
    // the attribute android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);

    // Add the adView to it
    layout.addView(adView);

    // Initiate a generic request to load it with an ad
    adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
  }

  @Override
  public void onDestroy() {
    if (adView != null) {
      adView.destroy();
    }
    super.onDestroy();
  }

}
```

**Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.tacomaapps.game"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" /> 

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_game"
    android:label="Cube Jump" >
    <activity
        android:name=".Splash"
        android:label="Cube Jump"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


    <activity
        android:name=".Menu"
        android:label="Cube Jump"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.tacomaapps.MENU" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".MyGameActivity"
        android:label="Cube Jump"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".HowToPlay"
        android:label="Cube Jump"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
          android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>        
</application>
```

**Main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/menuback"
android:baselineAligned="true"
android:orientation="horizontal" >


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="210dp"
    android:layout_weight="1.0"
    android:weightSum="100" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bFillSpace"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="45"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bStart"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="63dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:background="@drawable/play" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bHTP"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="63dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:background="@drawable/htp_button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bFillSpace2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="45"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:text="Button" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It crashes.. but without a **STACKTRACE** we can't help you.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm pretty new at this. How do I perform or get the info from a stacktrace?

Comment: Read this: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is perfectly fine and runs at my end.

I would like you to Verify following thing.

1 **You have created "libs" folder in project and added GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-X.X.X.jar there** and reference it from there.By default, they doesn't exist.**If you are directly referencing jar file from \extras\google\admob_ads_sdk then program crashes with** `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.ads.AdView` Strange but true.

You project structure should look something like this

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! Thanks to your image I was able to find out my error. I placed the whole GoogleAdMobAdsSdkAndroid-6.0.1 folder in by "libs" directory instead of just the .jar file.

Comment: haha.also just one suggestion whenever you want to reference to any jar file then create libs folder under project and copy that jar file there and reference it from there.Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the jar file as mentioned [here](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/android/fundamentals)